PowerBI - Dax query
I’m working on a DAX formula in Power BI to fetch the latest available buying_rate from an exchange_rate table based on the currency_id and the created_at date in an order table. The exchange_rate table doesn’t update daily, so if there’s no rate for the exact date, it should use the most recent rate available before that date.
For each transaction in the order table, the BuyingRate column should show the correct buying_rate for the currency_id and transaction_date, pulling from the most recent date where the rate was available if it's not recorded for that specific day.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
